# How do you show desktop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, taskbar, icons, shortcuts

In Windows XP, you get a 'Show Desktop' shortcut button in your task bar by default.

This does not appear in Windows 7.  How do I add a shortcut button in Windows 7 to show the desktop and hide the windows of all running applications?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally you should hover your mouse on the small rectangle on the right of the clock. It will trigger [**AeroPeek**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/peek), which makes the windows transparent and let you see the desktop.

If you really want a "Show desktop" button on the taskbar, follow [**this tutorial**](http://windows7center.com/tutorials/how-to-really-pin-the-show-desktop-to-taskbar-in-windows-7/).

You can also use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: If you actually click the button it will also perform "Show desktop".

Answer (score 1):

Guide here [www.askvg.com/](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-the-good-old-show-desktop-feature-back-in-windows-7/)

Or use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

can also use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (minimizes all), and then <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (toggles them back)

Comment: That’s not what was asked. This should be a comment.