# Is it possible to move the show desktop icon left in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Like how it used to be in Vista and XP, right next to the start menu on the bottom left as opposed to the bottom right as it is now in 7. I just upgraded and I'm finding it tough to adjust.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/94000/how-do-you-show-desktop-in-windows-7

Comment: You know; a corner is actually way easier targeted than an icon in a random location on the screen (or even on an edge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now might be a good opportunity to get yourself used to using <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to do this. Most unlikely MS can get their positions changed across Windows upgrade :)

Comment: ha, I actually didn't know that shortcut. I use shortcuts for everything might as well use it for this, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

That feature has been removed from Windows 7(means will be available on the right end of taskbar) . But there are some few articles on this getting it back.This is kind of tweak/ workaround solutions.

Follow the instruction given in this site -> [Askvg](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-the-good-old-show-desktop-feature-back-in-windows-7/)